# Issue with Docker php extension The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: php, docker

please help me on how to resolve this issue, im new to docker, when i try to build the docker compose up -d i got the below error

The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed

here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mariadb-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    nano \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
    zip
RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add zlib-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-zlib-dir=/usr \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www
# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```